# Python calculator taking string input

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, math-expression-eval

It accepts string input like `'1+1'` instead of `num1 = 1, num2 = 2, operation = '+'` or something like that.

```
def Numbers(var):
    return var == '0' or var == '1' or var == '2' or var == '3' or var == '4' or var == '5' or var == '6' or var == '7' or var == '8' or var == '9'

def Test4Num(varstr):
    n = 0
    var = ''
    try: 
        while Numbers(varstr[n]):
            var += varstr[n]
            n += 1
    except: pass
    return (int(var), n)

def operation(string, num1, num2):
    if string == '+':
        return num1 + num2
    if string == '-':
        return num1-num2
    if string == '*':
        return num1*num2
    if string == '/':
        return num1/num2
    if string == '^':
        return num1 ** num2

def operator(operato):
    return operato == '+' or operato == '-' or operato == '*' or operato == '/' or operato == '^'


negate = False
char = input('')

print(char + '=')
while True:
    try: 
        if char[0] == '-': #for negative numbers
            negate = True #because here the numbers are string format
            char = char[1:]
        number1 = Test4Num(char)[0]
        if negate == True:
            number1 = -number1
            negate = False
        end_number1 = Test4Num(char)[1]
        char = char[end_number1:]
        if char == '':
            print(number1)
            break
        op = char[0]
        char = char[1:]
        number2 = Test4Num(char)[0]
        end_number2 = Test4Num(char)[1]
        result = operation(op, number1, number2)
        number1 = result
        char = str(number1) + char[end_number2:]
        print(char)
    except: break
#created by Estoria Wandertag, while he was sitting on the toilet and thought about life and programming
```

This code is pretty straightforward, I mean it doesn't use class, any imports, etc. (ok, it can just use the 5 main operations in math, but that's extendable) and even though it's easy, I didn't find it on the internet...
So that's the reason I wanted to share this. If you have ideas, please share them. I'm pretty new here and also I haven't been using Python for very long, so there are plenty of things to add, I guess. (Sorry for my awful English, I'm German)

Answer (score 8):

On top of the other very good answers:

**Code organisation and tests**

It is a good idea to separate the logic about input/output from the logic computing results. In your case, you could have a function taking an expression as a string and returning a number.

This makes your code easier to understand, easier to reuse and more testable.

Also, it is a good habit to put your code actually calling the logic behind an [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

All of this taken into account, you have:

```
def eval_math_expr(expr):
    negate = False
    while True:
        try: 
            if expr[0] == '-': #for negative numbers
                negate = True #because here the numbers are string format
                expr = expr[1:]
            number1 = Test4Num(expr)[0]
            if negate == True:
                number1 = -number1
                negate = False
            end_number1 = Test4Num(expr)[1]
            expr = expr[end_number1:]
            if expr == '':
                return number1
            op = expr[0]
            expr = expr[1:]
            number2 = Test4Num(expr)[0]
            end_number2 = Test4Num(expr)[1]
            result = operation(op, number1, number2)
            number1 = result
            expr = str(number1) + expr[end_number2:]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
    return number1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    interactive = False
    if interactive:
        expr = input('Enter your expression:')
        print(expr + '=')
        print(eval_math_expr(expr))
    else:
        for expr, res in {"2": 2, "2*4": 8, "4+8": 12, "100/3": 33, "2^3": 8}.items():
            result = eval_math_expr(expr)
            if res != result:
                print("Computing", expr, "got", result, "instead of", res)
```

I also took this chance to remove the silent catch of exceptions which makes things hard to understand when an error occurs.

By the way, bare except (with no explicit exception type caught) and ignored exceptions are usually frowned upon as they make debugging very painful.

**Naming**

Your function names are not very good. Your could define `is_digit`, `get_number`, `perform_operation`.

**Simplify `is_digit` function**

The best data structure for the check you want to perform is a set.
You could write something like:

```
DIGITS = set('0123456789')

def is_digit(var):
    return var in DIGITS
```

**Simplify `perform_operation`**

The best data structure for the logic you want to perform is a dictionnary mapping operators to functions.

```
import operator

OPERATIONS = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.floordiv,
    '^' : operator.pow,
}


def perform_operation(string, num1, num2):
    op = OPERATIONS.get(string, None)
    if op is not None:
        return op(num1, num2)
    else:
        return None  # How to handle this?
```

Note: using `floordiv` instead of `truediv` fixes an issue found with tests mentionned above.

**Simplify `get_number`**

In Python, you usually don't need to get elements from an object by index. What you want is usually to iterate over the different elements. I highly recommand reading/watching [Ned Batchelder talk called "Loop Like A Native"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). In your case, you could write something like:

```
def get_number(varstr):
    s = ""
    for c in varstr:
        if not is_digit(c):
            break
        s += c
    return (int(s), len(s))
```

**Using tuple unpacking**

As already said, you could use `number1, end_number1 = get_number(expr)` to call `get_number` only once.

At this stage, the code looks like:

```
import operator

DIGITS = set('0123456789')
OPERATIONS = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.floordiv,
    '^' : operator.pow,
}


def is_digit(var):
    return var in DIGITS

def get_number(varstr):
    s = ""
    for c in varstr:
        if not is_digit(c):
            break
        s += c
    return (int(s), len(s))

def perform_operation(string, num1, num2):
    op = OPERATIONS.get(string, None)
    if op is not None:
        return op(num1, num2)
    else:
        return None  # How to handle this?

def eval_math_expr(expr):
    negate = False
    while True:
        try: 
            if expr[0] == '-': #for negative numbers
                negate = True #because here the numbers are string format
                expr = expr[1:]
            number1, end_number1 = get_number(expr)
            expr = expr[end_number1:]
            if negate == True:
                number1 = -number1
                negate = False
            if expr == '':
                return number1
            op = expr[0]
            expr = expr[1:]
            number2, end_number2 = get_number(expr)
            result = perform_operation(op, number1, number2)
            number1 = result
            expr = str(number1) + expr[end_number2:]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
    return number1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    interactive = False
    if interactive:
        expr = input('Enter your expression:')
        print(expr + '=')
        print(eval_math_expr(expr))
    else:
        for expr, res in {"2": 2, "2*4": 8, "4+8": 12, "100/3": 33, "2^3": 8, "-2": -2, "-2-3": -5}.items():
            result = eval_math_expr(expr)
            if res != result:
                print("Computing", expr, "got", result, "instead of", res)
```

**About `negate`**

You set `negate` to False at the very beginning and make sure you reset it back to False at each iteration so that the next iteration works fine. It would be clearer to initialise it to False at the beginning of the iteration. You could also set it to `negate = expr[0] == '-'`.

```
        negate = expr[0] == '-' #for negative numbers
        if negate:
            expr = expr[1:]
        number1, end_number1 = get_number(expr)
        expr = expr[end_number1:]
        if negate:
            number1 *= -1
```

An alterative could be to handle this as part of the `get_number` function.

```
def get_number(varstr):
    s = ""
    if varstr[0] == '-':
        s += "-"
        varstr = varstr[1:]
    for c in varstr:
        if not is_digit(c):
            break
        s += c
    return (int(s), len(s))


def eval_math_expr(expr):
    while True:
        try: 
            number1, end_number1 = get_number(expr)
            expr = expr[end_number1:]
            if expr == '':
                return number1
            op = expr[0]
            expr = expr[1:]
            number2, end_number2 = get_number(expr)
            number1 = perform_operation(op, number1, number2)
            expr = str(number1) + expr[end_number2:]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
    return number1
```

The whole code is:

```
import operator

DIGITS = set('0123456789')
OPERATIONS = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.floordiv,
    '^' : operator.pow,
}


def is_digit(var):
    return var in DIGITS

def get_number(varstr):
    s = ""
    if varstr[0] == '-':
        s += "-"
        varstr = varstr[1:]
    for c in varstr:
        if not is_digit(c):
            break
        s += c
    return (int(s), len(s))

def perform_operation(string, num1, num2):
    op = OPERATIONS.get(string, None)
    if op is not None:
        return op(num1, num2)
    else:
        return None  # How to handle this?

def eval_math_expr(expr):
    while True:
        try: 
            number1, end_number1 = get_number(expr)
            expr = expr[end_number1:]
            if expr == '':
                return number1
            op = expr[0]
            expr = expr[1:]
            number2, end_number2 = get_number(expr)
            number1 = perform_operation(op, number1, number2)
            expr = str(number1) + expr[end_number2:]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
    return number1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    interactive = False
    if interactive:
        expr = input('Enter your expression:')
        print(expr + '=')
        print(eval_math_expr(expr))
    else:
        for expr, res in {"2": 2, "2*4": 8, "4+8": 12, "100/3": 33, "2^3": 8, "-2": -2, "-2-3": -5}.items():
            result = eval_math_expr(expr)
            if res != result:
                print("Computing", expr, "got", result, "instead of", res)
```

**Reorganisation in the main function**

At the moment, the code parses two number and an operation, computes the operation, convert the result into a string to be parsed at next iteration. Thus, each temporary result gets converted from integer to string then integer. This leads to issues when the result cannot be converted back and forth - for instance when you perform divisions with non-integer result. Also this could be optimised a lot with the following logic:

- get the first number and store it as the current number
- in each iteration: get the operation and the next number. Compute the operation and store the result as the current number, to be reused at next iteration.
- at the end, return the current number.

You could write this:

```
def eval_math_expr(expr):
    n, end_n = get_number(expr)
    expr = expr[end_n:]
    while expr:
        op, expr = expr[0], expr[1:]
        n2, end_n = get_number(expr)
        n = perform_operation(op, n, n2)
        expr = expr[end_n:]
    return n
```

Comment: `var.isdigit()` might be faster than `var in DIGITS`, since it is a built-in and probably implemented in C.

Comment: Good point indeed!

Comment: except that uses a different definition of integer digits than `'0123456789'`

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't go to the same stream as the program output. Look into using the `logging` module

Comment: For the test harness I'd use a list of tuples instead of a `dict` since we're not ever indexing by key. That also removes the need for `.items()`

Comment: @Snowbody Good points! I do not know why I have the habit of storing tests in dictionnary when tuples are just as fine... As for the logging, it is much better indeed but I didn't want to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for your efford helping me! I didn't use          if __name__ == '__main__', because I didnt understand it. I already named the functions differently. But I dont understand the last part. As I said I'm new to python ^^ Thank you!

Comment: (How do you comment correctly? O_o I don't get it...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Regarding the "if main", I guess the best is to read the explanation, let this sink in for a night and try again tomorrow. As for the last part, the point is to avoid re-adding numbers you've computed to the expression you are about to parse. Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation, I'll be happy to try to provide it.

Answer (score 6):

your english is more than good ;)

Very small comments to give some advice at this level:

- Try a bit better naming for functions, is vital for anyone that will read your code to help understand them. Imagine someone has to read for example your first function `Numbers(var)` and try and figure out what it does just with that name. I would suggest a naming like `is_digit(character)` where is easy to understand what the functions does (checks if something is digit) and what kind of parameter it expects (a single character)
- Tedious comparisons of a single character, like `var == '0' or...` can be better written using python `in` operator. What about `var in '0123456789'`
- Same naming you can use for `def operator(operato):`, what about `is_operator(character)`
- The content of the while clause is a bit big, you may consider dividing it into functions

Last but not least

```
#created by Estoria Wandertag, while he was sitting on the toilet and thought about life and programming
```

That's a very literal approach to dumping data in the internet ;)

Comment: Thank you for advising me. I should definetely name the functions somehow else than that, you're totally right. I didnt know, that there was an in operator... :D  To the fourth mentioned point: Are there negative effects on the while loop, or is it just clearer? I wanted to that and Thanks! (to the last point: It's True and there aren't that many people who would want to substitude my name with theirs ^^)

Comment: Oh and it's not my English, but it's the editors English (I forgot apostrophies and he wrote 'straightforward'. Then I was confused because I didn't write 'straightforward')

Comment: It's more clear for anyone reading the code, including you :)

Answer (score 6):

When you're writing a computer program in any language, one of your goals should be to eliminate duplicated code. Computers are good at doing the same task over and over again, even with slightly different data.

A. Romeu has pointed out that you can use Python's `in` operator to find if a character is one of a set of characters. But there are other places where Python includes language features that could greatly simplify your code.

For instance, take a look at your `operation()` function. Note that the code is repeated, with just the operator being different:

> ```
> def operation(string, num1, num2):
>     if string == '+':
>         return num1 + num2
>     if string == '-':
>         return num1-num2
>     if string == '*':
>         return num1*num2
>     if string == '/':
>         return num1/num2
>     if string == '^':
>         return num1 ** num2
> ```

The usual way to do something like this in Python is to pre-construct a `dict` mapping the items to functions performing those actions, then pull the functions out of the `dict`.

In this case, since you're using operators, and those can't be stored in a `dict`, you'll need to `import operator` to get the function versions of the operators. Then below the import statement you can say

```
operations = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.truediv}

def operation(operator, num1, num2):
    return operations[operator](num1, num2)
```

No more duplicated code!

As for your main code, there are a number of things to improve, but I want to focus on the duplicated code. You have lines saying:

```
    number1 = Test4Num(char)[0]
    # ...
    end_number1 = Test4Num(char)[1]
```

so you have two calls to `Test4Num(char)`. Instead, use Python's multiple assignment feature (also called tuple assignment):

```
    (number1, end_number1) = Test4Num(char)
```

This assigns to both `number` and `end_number1`.

Also I think your final `print()` is unnecessary; it prints out partial intermediate results just run together; you just want the end result, right?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! I made the code in an app, where I wasn't sure, if I was able to import things. I didn't know the second improvement proposal, thanks again. But the print() was meant, because I wanted to see all results in between and show, that it doesnt calculate '/' or '*' before '+' or '-'. Thanks!

Comment: Importing is part and parcel of Python. If your app doesn't let you use `import`, it's not giving you Python.

Comment: Debugging statements should be separate from the rest of your code, for instance using the `logging` module via `import logging`.

Answer (score 2):

There is one flaw in your code, that I can't pass. If I first put a positive number and then a negative, such as `3*-3`, it won't do anything. It just ends and that's all.

Answer (score -1):

If the input contains only numbers in the string format we can use `eval()` in Python
ex:`eval("1+2+3")`

Comment: Really not a good idea. At the least, if you're going to ask the interpreter to do this for you, use `ast`; but even that is too poorly-constrained for this problem.